# Generate method stub on code with too many {

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I just noticed that when you try to generate a method stub on code where there are more `{` than `}`, the method stub gets generated incorrectly.

For instance:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        myMethod();
    }
```

creating a method stub for `myMethod()` expands correctly into:

```
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        myMethod();
    }

    private static void myMethod() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

However! If I now continue and add:

```
{
    newMethod();
```

And try to generate a method stub for `newMethod()`, I get this:

```
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            myMethod();
            {
                newMethod();
        }

        private

private static void newMethod()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
} static void myMethod() {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Can I configure Visual Studio somehow as to do it correctly? Or is this something that would have to be reported to someone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is a case of garbage in, garbage out.

If your code is written in such a way that it's impossible for the auto-generation tools to tell where one code block ends and another begins then I wouldn't expect it to be able to produce meaningful results.

Comment: never heard of the expression garbage in, garbage out.. Oh, you mean my code is garbage? hehe.. Well, I though it looked at the current functions, something like -- insert in between a `}` and a "`public|private return_value function_name()`" row --

Comment: @Michael Only in that you're giving it a known unparsable/compilable piece of code and asking it to parse/compile it correctly.

Comment: Also, it does find it's way out into the class. It's not iterated through too many }, but still enough to exit the function I'm in (at the moment `Main`). So I do think it knows somewhat where it is.. Although, I'm just guessing..

Comment: The fact remains that you can't have a mis-match in braces, that results in uncompilable code, yet according to the question you do. That there is the root cause of your problem. The auto-generation tool *may* get it right, or nearly right, given _invalid_ input, but the way to be sure it *will* get it right is to give it _valid_ input.

Answer (score 0):

If you consider this behavior a bug, I recommend reporting it to [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/).

Of course, the simple solution is to have well-formatted code prior to using code gen and automated refactor routines. I can't imagine how the text editor could "correctly" handle the potentially-unlimited variety of malformed code.

Comment: well, at least not insert it into another methods head :)